# product not display for sub category in magento

Tags: magento

I am new for the mageneto

I use my own theme after that I insert category and subcategory for that for that subcategory I insert product but the product will not display for that subcategory and even in home page

shade (category click on that)-> solarshade(subcategory)-> click on that i want to show image for solarshade catgory but it will not display me the product for that category

I am stucked for this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you product is ready to be displayed in your category.

check these attributes of product

In General tab:

```
status => enabled
Visibility => Catalog(if you want product to be appear in search result too then use Catalog,Search)
```

In Inventory tab

```
Qty => (provide some quantity)
Stock Availability => In Stock
```

And finally in Category tab make sure that your desired category is selected in tree.

Then try these direct URL's to confirm that there nothing wrong with you product and category

To confirm product is getting displayed

```
{base_url}/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/{your product ID}
```

To confirm product is getting displayed under your desired category

```
{base_url}/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/{your product ID}/category/{your category ID}
```

You can get your product id and category id from manage product and manage category respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay

But I check this all the things for that kind of changes
I get this kind of error in consol

http://localhost/shadewindow/index.php/submenuz/Index/show_cat/ -NOT FOUND

Comment: I'm not much clear about what console error you are getting.May be you should write whole error text not partial. And if you have done all above things then 'm appending my answer with few more checks. so try my updated answer.

Comment: it's full error which i show in consol not more then that so i can't find out mistake